# Finding edge connectivity of a network by using Maximum Flow algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I want to find the edge connectivity (i.e. minimum number of edges to remove to disconnect a graph) of an undirected graph using maximum flow algorithms (Edmond Karp / Ford-Fulkerson algorithms) ,

I know that I can accomplish this task by finding the minimum maximum flow between every two nodes of a graph , but this would result O(|V| ^ 2) number of flow networks ,

```
int Edge-Connectivity(Graph G){
    int min = infinite;
    for (Vertex u: G.V){
        for (Vertex v: G.V){
           if (u != v){ 
             //create directed graph Guv (a graph with directed edges and source u and sink v)
             //run Edmonds-Karp algorithm to find the maximum flow |f*|
             if (min > |f*|)
               min = |f*|;
           }    
         }
     }
     return min;
}
```

But I'd like to do this with |V| flow networks (running the max flow algorithm for only O(|V|) times) instead of O(|V| ^ 2) of them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Distinguish a node `v` in your graph.  Compute, for every `w` other than `v`, the maximum flow from `v` to `w`.  Since `v` must be on one shore of the graph's global minimum cut and something else must be on the other side, one of these flows will identify the global minimum cut.

There's a trick due to Hao and Orlin where, if you use a preflow push algorithm, a global minimum-cut computation takes about as much time as a minimum (s,t)-cut problem.  It has the benefit of being practical.  Karger has a randomised algorithm that does it in O(n polylog(n)) time, but I'm not aware of any implementations, let alone fast implementations.

Comment: The max-flow detection algorithm is not of concern here , I only wanted to know if I have to compute the max-flow for every two nodes (which seems not to be necessary as the graph is undirected !)

Comment: By tmyklebu's answer(first paragraph), you don't need to compute every two nodes. Fix a node v, iterating all possible w != v and compute maximum flow is enough. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph#Computational_aspects

Comment: @Yu-HanLyu: Yes; that's exactly what I said.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the algorithm by Karger, but wikipedia suggests that the correct complexity would be n^2 polylog n (expected) time.

Comment: @G.Bach: The paper's called something like "Minimum cuts in near-linear time."  As you might expect from the title, it proposes an algorithm for finding a minimum cut in nearly-linear time.

Comment: Ah, yeah you're right, that's [exactly what it's called](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/9812007). Couldn't find that via wiki, thanks for that.

Comment: I dont get the explanation why using only 1 vertex works, can you explain better please?