# Minimum cut in a non directed graph with links without weight

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I need to found the minimum cut in a non directed graph. I know this is possible by using any flow algorithm, like Ford-Fulkerson, Edmonds Karp or Relable-to-Front. But since the links have no weight (or all have the same weight). Is this possible to solve by just using a DFS or a BFS? Note, I just need to know the number of links that are cut, no need to find which links.

Thanks.

Comment: How would the "weight" contribute to the problem? Are you interested in a weight-minimal cut?

Comment: the weight is not needed to the problem.

Comment: You are basically asking for the connectivity of a graph, i.e. if it's k-connected. Biconnectivity can be decided with one DFS (I think), and beyond that it's all flows afaik.

Comment: I've already tried it with a DFS but theres still a condition missing.

Comment: @G. Bach Note that for a cut, either partition needs to contain either the source or the terminal node; or is the question about a directed graph in general and not a flow problem in the stricter sense?

Comment: the graph is undirected as I said. And the problem can be solved as a flow problem. I just want to know if I can solve this without transforming the problem into a flow problem.

Comment: Also in this case if I solve the problem with a DFS I have an O(V + E), but if I solved it with a flow algorithm I can have like O(V|max flow|), O(VE^2), or a O(V^3)  depending on the algorithm i use .

Comment: I'm thinking about something like for each visited node, I determine how many paths I have to this node, and how many paths I have from this node to the objective node.

Comment: @LuisAlves I'm not aware of an algorithm that calculates the edge connectivity of a graph without using flows. There are algorithms for 1-connectivity and 2-connectivity only using BFS/DFS, but - to my knowledge - for any larger k, all algorithms calculating whether a graph is k-connected do so by using flows.

Comment: Ok,thanks anyway. I've already lost some hours trying to solve this by using a DFS and I seems that I'm failing in some particular case. So I'm just going to transform the problem into a flow problem.

Comment: This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384151/finding-edge-connectivity-of-a-network-by-using-maximum-flow-algorithm